# Zoom action in android using appium-python-client

Tags: android, python, zooming, appium, python-appium

Does anybody know how to zoom an element in android via appium python client?

I am currently using

`self.driver.zoom(self.element, percent)` but this gives an error

```
self.driver.zoom(self.element, percent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 308, in zoom
self.execute_script('mobile: pinchOpen', opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 461, in execute_script
{'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
raise wde
WebDriverException: Message: Method has not yet been implemented
```

I also tried through `MultiAction`.

```
loc = self.element.location
print loc
xx, yy = loc["x"], loc["y"]
xx=700
action1 = TouchAction(self.driver)
action1.long_press(x=xx, y=yy).move_to(x=0, y=1000).release()
action2 = TouchAction(self.driver)
action2.long_press(x=xx, y=yy).move_to(x=0, y=-1000).release()
m_action = MultiAction(self.driver)
m_action.add(action1, action2)
m_action.perform()
```

But again this does not perform any zoom.Instead it scrolls down the list.Does anybody have any idea about what's wrong here.

`Appium Logs`

```
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"83"}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: getLocation
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"x":0,"y":1225}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getLocation() result: {"x":0,"y":1225}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/c1a4d17f-0dc6-4445-bfad-776ec65bddb5/element/83/location 200 26 ms - 88 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/c1a4d17f-0dc6-4445-bfad-776ec65bddb5/touch/multi/perform {"sessionId":"c1a4d17f-0dc6-4445-bfad-776ec65bddb5","actions":[[{"action":"longPress","options":{"y":1225,"x":700,"duration":1000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"y":1000,"x":0}},{"action":"release","options":{}}],[{"action":"longPress","options":{"y":1225,"x":700,"duration":1000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"y":-1000,"x":0}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]]}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.performMultiAction() with args: [[[{"action":"longPress","o...
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"performMultiPointerGesture","params":{"actions":[[{"action":"longPress","time":0.005,"touch":{"y":1225,"x":700,"duration":1000}},{"action":"moveTo","time":0.01,"touch":{"y":2225,"x":700}}],[{"action":"longPress","time":0.005,"touch":{"y":1225,"x":700,"duration":1000}},{"action":"moveTo","time":0.01,"touch":{"y":225,"x":700}}]]}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"performMultiPointerGesture","params":{"actions":[[{"action":"longPress","time":0.005,"touch":{"y":1225,"x":700,"duration":1000}},{"action":"moveTo","time":0.01,"touch":{"y":2225,"x":700}}],[{"action":"longPress","time":0.005,"touch":{"y":1225,"x":700,"duration":1000}},{"action":"moveTo","time":0.01,"touch":{"y":225,"x":700}}]]}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: performMultiPointerGesture
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.performMultiAction() result: "OK"
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c1a4d17f-0dc6-4445-bfad-776ec65bddb5/touch/multi/perform 200 133 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/c1a4d17f-0dc6-4445-bfad-776ec65bddb5 {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MultiAction attempt looks good, but after testing a bit on my phone's native camera app, I was able to get a nice zoom gesture by adding 500ms wait() after the moveTo():

```
# Zoom
action1.long_press(x=xx, y=yy).move_to(x=0, y=50).wait(500).release()
action2.long_press(x=xx, y=yy).move_to(x=0, y=-50).wait(500).release()
m_action.add(action1, action2)

# Pinch
action3.long_press(x=xx, y=yy-50).move_to(x=0, y=50).wait(500).release()
action4.long_press(x=xx, y=yy+50).move_to(x=0, y=-50).wait(500).release()
m_action2.add(action3, action4)

m_action.perform()
m_action2.perform()
```

This resulted in a nice and slow zoom to the camera app. Without the wait() the gestures were too quick and didn't really do much. It is mentioned at Appium's documentation at Github, that wait() can be used to control the timing of a gesture: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions.md

I set the `xx` and `yy` to the middle of the screen in my camera app with:

```
xx = self.driver.get_window_size()['width']/2
yy = self.driver.get_window_size()['height']/2
```

Please remember that coordinates should never go out of device screen bounds, so checks for screen borders may be useful, if you want to make this into a re-usable function.

I also couldn't use the MultiAction gestures when automating Chrome (not even when changing to NATIVE_APP context. The gestures had no effect.) so it's possible that using MultiActions on WebView scenarios isn't supported.

Comment: I think that the 500ms will work fine in most cases. I added a link to docs where the `wait` is mentioned to be meant exactly for the purpose of timing a gesture. Could you mark my answer accepted, if it helped you out?

Comment: Added a pinch gesture to the answer. Seemed to work with exactly the opposite gesture by adjusting the beginning coordinate and direction.

Comment: This solution not working for me on appium version 1.9.1